# jQuery перезапустить функцию

Tags: jquery

При создании страницы запускается таймер, я хочу чтобы при движении мыши по странице таймер запускался по новой. Но сейчас работает не корректно.
Например отсчет идет с 5:00 и доходит до 4:30 в этот момент я дергаю мышью и таймер обновился до 5:00 а потом резко продолжает с 4:30, а надо чтобы продолжался 4:59, 58, 57 и.т.д. Как правильно перезапустить функцию?

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
            timer();
        });

        $('body').on('mousemove mousedown',function(){
            timer();
        });

function timer() {
            var duration = 60 * 5;
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

            setInterval(function() { // запускаем интервал
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                if (--timer < 0) {
                //обновить таймер timer = duration;
                        location.reload();
            }
                $('#timer').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }, 1000);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вынес переменные  `timer`, `minutes` и `seconds` из функции старта таймера в общую область видимости с функцией слушающей движения мышки и клики, в которой переинициализирую их

```
  timer = duration;
  minutes = 0;
  seconds = 0;
```

```js
var duration = 60 * 5;
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

$( document ).ready(function(){
    startTimer();
});

$(window).on('mousemove mousedown',function(){
  timer = duration;
  minutes = 0;
  seconds = 0;
});

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(function() { // запускаем интервал
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
        //обновить таймер timer = duration;
                location.reload();
        }
        $('#timer').text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!